# Is a tensor product of two dvrs semilocal? 

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Under what conditions is the tensor product of two dvrs semilocal?

The same question about being reduced.

Tensor product is taken over another dvr or over a field to make things simpler.

For example, $\mathbb Z_p \otimes_{\mathbb Z_p} \mathbb Z_p$ is clearly reduced. What is (a highbrow) reason for this?

Comment: The tensor products of two fields over a common subfield $k$ is in general not reduced, but it is if one of the two is separable over $k$.

Comment: Thank you. What if at least one of the rings is not a field? 

Answer (score 2):

If the two dvrs $S$ and $T$ are torsion-free over the base dvr $R$, then $S$ and $T$ are flat over $R$. So the tensor product is flat over $S$ (and over $T$). Therefore if the tensor products of the quotient fields $Q(S)\otimes_{Q(R)}Q(T)$ is reduced, then so is $S \otimes_R T$.